# Is it possible to convert Azure blob storage content accesed via SAS link

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We have files stored in Azure storage blob. When a client needs access to them, they request it via our back end and we provide them with a [SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview) link to it.

Recently we have got a client to our API which can only consume Base64 encoded content. We can extend the API to return Base64 encoded files, and we did it as a temporary work around. However, it requires to read the whole content and proxy it via the API.

We can write an Azure http-triggered function to encode - which will not be that different from extending the API. Another option would be saving Base64 encoded copies of documents.

Is it possible the Azure Storage has an embedded way to return the content encoded into base64? If not, what would be the best approach to convert? The criteria is infrastructure payments. The load is almost entirely read with occasional inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Storage doesn't provide a way to transform data on its own. Your approach of using a proxy that performs the transformation would be the way to go.